# JSON.parse without escaping

Tags: javascript, python, json

Is there anyway to do this in JavaScript:

```
$ cat test.json 
{"body":"\u0000"}

$ python3 -c 'import json; print(json.load(open("test.json", "r")))'
{'body': '\x00'}
```

Notice, the data above only one `\` (does not need to be escaped).  So you have the following situation in JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse('{"body":"\\u0000"}') // works
JSON.parse('{"body":"\u0000"}') // does not work
```

With potentially any UTF-8 data comming from a binary source (websocket), can this data be processed directly like in the first python example above?

Comment: In Javascript, like in Python, ``\`` has special meaning when defining a string. You have to double it to ``\\`` to remove than special meaning. The *resulting string value* will really only have one backslash, followed by the character `u`, etc.

Comment: In the `test.json` file you are not defining a Python or Javascript string literal, so no, there are no doubled backslashes there.

Comment: In ECMAscript 6 there is a [`String.raw` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) that  could give you what you want: ``JSON.parse(String.raw`{"body":"\u0000"}`)``

Comment: Last but not least, data coming in from a websocket is data and not a string literal, so backslashes won't be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

String characters from `\u0000` through `\u001F` are considered as control characters, and according to [RFC-7159](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159) are not allowed characters to use in JSON and must be escaped, as stated [in section 7](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159#rfc.section.7).

What you are trying to do is to put unescaped control characters into a JSON, which clearly not acceptable, you have to escape it first, non of the languages accept it, even Python.

The correct answer would be place a UTF-8 encoded value into a string containing a JSON format.

This is a correct JSON, and will be parsed by any JSON parser in any language, even in JavaScript:

```
{"body":"\u0000"}
```

This is **incorrect** JSON (consider the `[NUL]` as a NUL control character, as it cannot be represented in text):

```
{"body":"[NUL]"}
```

That's why `JSON.parse('{"body":"\\u0000"}')` works and `JSON.parse('{"body":"\u0000"}')` doesn't.

Hope, it clarifies what's wrong with your test.